# Python-generated MySQL SELECT query not returning full list of results

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I am writing a Python3 script that takes a number inputted by a user and assigns it to a variable called "set_budget", which is then used to construct a MySQL `SELECT` query. I'm using the MySQLdb database connector library. The relevant section of my code looks like this:

```
set_budget = ''
set_budget = sys.argv[1]

budget = ''
if set_budget == '0':
            budget = '10.00'
    elif set_budget == '1':
            budget = '25.00'
    elif set_budget == '2':
            budget = '50.00'
    else:
            print('Enter "0" for $10.00, "1" for $25.00, and "2" for $50.00')

budget_query = ("SELECT park_name FROM parks WHERE admission_price <= " + budget)

cursor = connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute (budget_query)
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
```

This should theoretically create a MySQL query like `SELECT park_name FROM parks WHERE admission_price <= 10.00` if the user inputs the number "0". The admission_price column is a decimal(5,2) field in the database.

When I query `SELECT park_name FROM parks WHERE admission_price <= 10.00` directly in MySQL it properly returns all of the parks where the admission_price is between 0.00 and 10.00.

However, when I run my Python script, only the parks with an admission price between 0.00 and 9.99 are returned. Moreover, if I select the $25.00 option by typing "1" in the script it inexplicably excludes some parks priced between 10.00 and 25.00 in addition to excluding parks where the admission_price is exactly 25.00.

Am I doing something wrong in the execution of this code or should I be using a different method to construct MySQL queries with Python?

Comment: Have you tried printing the budget_query after it is assigned a value to ensure the end result is the same as what you query in MySQL?

Comment: I have a theory. Try this query in MySQL: `SELECT park_name FROM parks WHERE admission_price <= '10.00'`

Comment: Ya, I was going to say Python will assume the datatype and since your concatenating a double to a string, it assumes the 10.00 is '10.00'

Comment: *script that takes a number inputted by a user*... do remember [Bobby Table](http://bobby-tables.com/) as a clever user can destroy your tables with such input. You should be parameterizing query.

Comment: @JacobBarnes ... and MySQL will not err out on such an evaluation as it implicitly casts string representation of numbers.

Comment: @JacobBarnes Yes, I have tried printing budget_query after it is assigned a value. It appears to be identical to the desired query.

Comment: @Parfait The production code will never be taking inputs from users. I just have it set up this way at the moment so I can test if the script is working before I finish the code that will actually supply the input numbers.

Comment: @Parfait I just tried the query you suggested in MySQL. It gave an identical result as the query without ' ' marks.

Comment: Nonetheless, do so anyways as there are additional benefits to SQL parameterization outside of sql injections. And try rendering *set_budget* as a float and not string. Finally, please provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show data. Else this is all hearsay.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the advice. I went back to my code to create a reproducible example and realized that the script is now working exactly as intended. I have no idea what fixed it because I didn't change anything, but restarting the server must have cleared the problem. (I turned the server off after posting my initial question.) I'll add an edit to my post in case anyone else encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with my code. When I restarted my Ubuntu 16.04 server the issue resolved itself. I'm not sure why this occurred but I will leave my question up in case anyone else experiences a similar problem.